# How to search in MySQL in a case-insensitive way

Tags: mysql

How can I search for a user even if I don't know the exact spelling with regards to case, like

```
SELECT * FROM USER WHERE U.NAME =  'STEVEN';
```

Meaning: if a user has the name "Steven" or "sTEVEN" how can I search all persons who have this name?

I tried it, but it does not work.

```
WHERE email LIKE '%GMAIL%'
```

It did not not work when case was lowercase.

Comment: What are the attributes of your NAME column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [UPPER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_upper)

```
SELECT * FROM USER WHERE UPPER(U.NAME) = 'STEVEN'
```

Comment: @InSane, for the example, if the name in the table is sTEVEN, the above SQL would work. 'STEVEN' in the SQL, I assume is something like a search parameter, so we can force that to be upper always.

Comment: try to  check them in like when your column set as utf unicode and try with both lower and upper case

Comment: @Nivas - i was referring to the parameter value having 'sTEVEN' - but like you said, if u use the above query, the search parameter has to be forced to be upper ... just somewhere else! That's fair enough!! just that it should be noted - for completeness..thats all!

Comment: WHERE email LIKE '%gmail%' try with it

Comment: @steven, an example please, of the SQL, what is in the table that is not returned in the result of the sql...

Comment: @steven, when you say `where upper(email) like ('%GMAIL%)`, and there is a `xyz@gMAiL.com` in the table, you don't get it in the results?

Comment: Properly configured database performing case insensitive search BY DEFAULT. By applying a function to a field contents you will disable index usage. with obvious consequences.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, yes. But what if I want both? (Almost) all cases not case sensitive, but just ont little search (for a report, say) that needs to search case sensitive....

Comment: USE COLLATION. That's what collations are for

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, I am not a DBA, nor an expert in databases. Heard of collation just from you. I am learning that right now (and I understand why you are furious).

Answer (score 5):

The case sensitivity is based on the character set and collation of the table.

> The default character set and
>   collation are latin1 and
>   latin1_swedish_ci, so nonbinary string
>   comparisons are case insensitive by
>   default.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

You may want to look at the collation of your table if the searches are case-sensitive.

Comment: +1, fixing it on the column is preferable to using UPPER/LOWER

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at using

[UPPER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_upper) and [LOWER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower)